# Excel formula for a series of percentage increases

Tags: percentages

So if for every level there is a 2 percent increase on top of the last level. What would the formula be?

Level 1: Health = 100

Level 2: Health = 102

Level 3: Health = 104.04

and so on.

I want to just be able to input the level and get a readout on the stat.

Comment: If cell `A1` contains $100$, then put `=A1*1.02` in cell `A2`, and copy/paste that as far down as you want to go. Each cell will be $1.02$ times the cell above it, which is $2\%$ growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic exponential growth.  You have a starting value of 100 at t=0, since you want that to be at 1 we use $t-1$ instead as the exponent for the increase of $.02$ to get to

$$Health(level)=100\cdot (1.02)^{level-1}$$

Comment: I think in Excel the function is named `pow()`, as in `pow(1.02, level - 1)`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!